# 15 amp 2-pole breaker, what wire size is needed

Tags: electrical

Homeowner says AC guys said unit requires a 15amp 2 pole breaker, does this mean 14/3 wire can be used ? Thought AC units required bigger wire and bigger breaker.

Answer (score 4):

Most traditional split systems that use the heating ductwork don't need the neutral. Some ductless minisplits do have some 120v control or condensate pump options that do require the neutral. So it depends on your system requirements if XX/2 or XX/3 is needed**.

As to size the unit should the unit should have a label that specifies two separate numbers, "Maximum Overcurrent Protection" that specifies breaker size, and "Minimum Circuit Ampacity" which applies to wire size. The wire needs to be rated for 125% of that number. So if using 60°C UF cable 14/3 is only good for MCA of 12A. I'm assuming your talking about UF since NM (Romex) can't enter a damp or wet location. If using THWN conductors #14 is good for 16A (using 310.16 75°C rating since 240.3 exempts A/C from 15A limit of 240.4).

Additionally the installation instructions may specify minimum size wire, the instructions are part of the UL/ETL/CSA Listing, and the NEC gives higher priority to the Listing than the general provisions in the Code.

**Just for clarity, nomenclature for cords (like appliance and extension cords) and cables (NM, MC, UF) are different as used by the NEC. A 14/3 cord counts the ground, cables like NM or UF don't count the ground even though present. So 14/3 UF cable would have 4 wires.

Comment: Last word "cable" in answer should be wire or conductor?

Comment: @JimStewart In my mind the "a" before the colors made the "cable" at the end refer back to "UF", but since it's unclear I did tweak it. I see other edits were needed, a reaction to a bee sting had my head spinning a bit when I posted.

Answer (score 0):

14/3 wire would be OK but considering the load and not knowing the distance I would suggest you use 12/2 with ground. You can run 12/3 with ground but it is not necessary. That would cover you in case the AC needs 110 but I very much doubt it.

Comment: Distance from panel to unit maybe35 feet

Comment: For the cost difference of the wire I would go with the #12, you may decide later you want a bigger unit.

Comment: 35 Ft does not present a voltage drop concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the label on the AC unit for the proper amperage. The compressor unit will normally be a smaller load than the air handler which might contain a heater. I have a three ton compressor unit that draws 21.5 Amps so I have #10/2 AWG and a 30 Amp breaker. The air handler with a heater has 6/3 with a 60 Amp breaker. Your wiring does seem a little small.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally check the unit specs, or call the "AC guys" yourself to verify - 14/2 is probably perfectly fine - you can oversize the wire and the size of the wire if it makes you or the homeowner happy, but I'm **suspecting a mini-split** and I know mine draw straight 240 V, no neutral needed, from a 15A breaker (actual minimum circuit ampacity 9.8A or so IIRC, typical draw on a non-extreme day considerably less.) So 14/2 and a 15A double-pole is plenty, and not even close to its limits.